# how to achieve following query with mongoid

Tags: mongoid

How to write following mongodb query with mongoid?

```
db.messages.find({ 
                             $or :[
                    { $and : [
                                                  {"receiver_id":"user1@gmail.com"},
                                                  {"sender_id":"user2@hotmail.com"}
                                    ]
                    },
                                    { $and : [
                           {"receiver_id":"user2@hotmail.com"},
                           {"sender_id":"user1@gmail.com"}
                    ]  
                    } 
                ] 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be same as:

```
Message.all.or("receiver_id":"user1@gmail.com","sender_id":"user2@hotmail.com").or("receiver_id":"user2@hotmail.com","sender_id":"user1@gmail.com")
```